# Make background color transparent in MapTiler?

Tags: mbtiles, transparency-opacity, maptiler

I have MapTiler 5.0.3 pro, and hundreds of 8-bit per band .tiff files with transparent channel Alpha. After batch conversion:

`"C:\Program Files\Maptiler Pro\maptiler.exe" -f png -nodata 0 0 0 -zoom 10 18 -store mbtiles -o "outfiles.mbtiles" input_files.tif`

and so on...

For some reason some of the output mbtiles have transparency (when load in QGIS, I see only image, without black and\or bounding box). Some output mbtiles have both white and black background (white bg is much bigger), and some only white. What is that?

The input .tiff files have the same metadata (4 bands, no compression). Documentation to MapTiler says, that if input files doesn't have transparency (e.g. jpeg or 3 band png (png8, png24)), MapTiler adds default White background. But, I have alpha band in input. I also tried make bgcolor black (0 0 0 ) and set nodata value (0 0 0), selected different -f options: png, png32, png24, png8, jpeg the result is the same. I also tried [tileserver.php](https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-php) but nothing helps. Nodata parameter works fine in most cases, but the white giant  background - I don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade to the latest version of MapTiler Pro. Version 0.5.3 is very old - and there has been a lot of improvements implemented since then.

The binaries of the latest version of MapTiler Pro are available by filling the form at http://www.maptiler.com/demo/

If you have trouble with your data processing workflow, you can submit a report information about your task and input data with "-report" parameter (or via the GUI a http://www.maptiler.com/how-to/submit-report/) and send it to info@klokantech.com. 
Then we investigate further, and if it is a problem related to your input data, we recommend a proper list of parameters.

You need to be a legal owner of a valid license for the software. There is no record of purchase under your name. Please provide your order identification when submitting a support request.